# Why is my Docker Symfony project consuming so much memory?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

### Description

I'm deploying my symfony project in prod. It works fine when I simply run `docker-compose up`. However I'm getting an issue with my deploy script and try accessing the web page in my navigator.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>   /var/www/redaph/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>   on line 107
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65536 bytes) in
>   /var/www/redaph/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

What is weird is that, in my dockerfile I specify that I want my PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT to be at 256M. When I enter my container I see the following:

```
root@125de315edca:/var/www/redaph# php -i | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
```

### Question

Why is my Docker Symfony project consuming so much memory?

If this is normal then:
How do I correctly increase the PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT in my dockerfile?

**deploy_prod.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECT=symfony
docker-compose up -d
docker exec redaph_symfony_1 php bin/console d:s:u --force
docker exec redaph_symfony_1 php bin/console c:c
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

ENV \
    APACHE_ADMIN_EMAIL=webmaster@localhost \
    PHP_TIME_ZONE=Europe/London \
    PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=256M \
    PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=32M \
    PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=32M

ARG WORK_DIR

WORKDIR $WORK_DIR

COPY composer.lock $WORK_DIR
COPY composer.json $WORK_DIR

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y -f apt-transport-https \
        libicu-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        acl \
        cron \
        git \
        zip \
    && pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        exif \
        gd \
        intl \
        opcache \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        zip \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data $WORK_DIR \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && service cron start
```

Comment: I can provide a snippet of my docker-compose.yml however I don't think the issue comes from there.

Comment: Are you expecting such a large memory usage? This implies to me you have code loop problems. Simply giving the problem more memory will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Martin when the error occurs, I checked my symfony logs and they are empty meaning that I never once entered my project. No, I'm not expecting such a large memory usage. Could this be caused by compser? I've seen similar issues on github regarding composer.

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898

Comment: So then the question should not be "How do I correctly increase the PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT in my dockerfile" but "Why is my Docker Symfony project consuming so much memory?"... maybe rewrite your question, eh? `:-)`

Comment: Ad 1: sometimes its caused by composer, you can try custom container which loads project with vendor and just run, no composer install/update. Ad 2: you dont see any error, because error is too big (stream handler error) so it couldnt be logged. Try to change buffer_size in monolog config

Comment: Are you sure the env PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT will set the cli memory_limit?

Comment: @jeremy no I'm not sure

Comment: From maintainers of the php docker images (https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/311). The best is to add your own ini file foreach env (cli, apache, fpm, ...) and then you will be able to manage memory_limit and all other config

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, and the cause was that the /var/log was not writable. For some reasons monolog, instead of saying the directory is not writable, it tried I guess constantly to write causing a memory leak ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems more likely the problem is the code / configuration of your app. Docker may not need to be touched.

Depending on the handler you have configured, look into limiting monolog's buffer size ([configuration code here](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) -- search for `buffer_size`).

With Composer, run `composer update` locally in dev. When deploying, run `composer install`. `update` takes more memory than `install` in order to to resolve the dependency graph, assuming install has a `composer.lock` to work with.

It looks like that is what is being done based on the dockerfile you posted, but maybe something else is happening/interfering with that somewhere along the way. I would verify `composer.lock` contains what you think it does, just in case.

You can also try the flag `memory_limit=-1` when you run composer:

`php -d memory_limit=-1 composer install rest-of-args-here`

If that's not enough, provide the version of Symfony you are using. Post your `composer.json` and Symfony configs related to monolog.

Comment: It's not composer that causes the problem but when I run the deploy_prod.sh script only. I don't think that setting the memory_limit=-1 is good in a prod environment.

Comment: Sure! Not a good thing to do in production. But it's a heck of a good thing to try and see if it makes a difference while troubleshooting the issue. We haven't pinpointed the problem yet, but you have two clues in your logs: monolog (buffer_size) and composer (is composer.lock not in place the way you think it is? Is composer trying to resolve dependencies upon deployment, instead of having that already accomplished?). So work on those first. My post gave you some things to try with both. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

It would help knowing what's on those lines where the errors are happening.

Regarding how to change your limit: MY "right way", there's basically 2 I can think of:

- place a RUN in dockerfile with a one-liner edit, this should work https://serverfault.com/questions/96372/sed-php-ini-memory-limit.
- keep a php.ini file on local which will be copied to the container. To make docker copy it, under your volume key in docker-compose file do a line

  - /ini/location/on/local:/ini/location/container

  I find this one messy for your case, i'd only do it if the file needed lots/continuous editing, which isn't the case.

There's another option but it would require you to do it every time you build which isn't really useful:

- docker exec -it whatever bash

From there you just edit the file, assuming you've got the right tools (sed, vim, whatever you want).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rottenoats/4c46617329e8a6e1be66dc8561218788 here is where it fails. I'm unable to get those errors specifically since they are not logged by symfony nor by apache.

Comment: Commonly I've seen/heard of this when it came to permissions, try to do a chmod 777 on the monolog logging directory (i'm assuming it's /APP_PATH/var/log). Don't run a chmod 777 on prod though. Other things you could do to check it out is just do a "classy" var_dump($this->errorMessage, $this->url) in StreamHandler above that line. Or use xdebug, ofc. If by any chance it's not dumping during your deploy, just do a docker exec bash and manually run your commands.